# Removing commands from input to command

Tags: macros, robust-commands

I'm trying to create my own command to highlight some changes. I want the command to update a counter, add a line in the contents table and do some changes in the text.

So far, I got:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\CoorAdd}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{change}%
\textcolor{blue}{#1}% 
\addcontentsline{tod}{subsection}{Correction \arabic{change}. Added: 
\textcolor{blue}{\substring{#1}{1}{20}}~% substring macro to cut the text to the first 20 characters
}
\ignorespaces}
```

which works great as long as there is no commands in the input. If I write `\CoorAdd{ in figure \Cref{fig.fig}}`, it generates a bunch of errors such as:

```
Argument of \@crefstar has an extra }. [...s.}}{1}{20}}\nobreakspace {}}{10}{change.34}]
Paragraph ended before \@crefstar was complete. [...s.}}{1}{20}}\nobreakspace {}}{10}{change.34}]
Undefined control sequence. [...s.}}{1}{20}}\nobreakspace {}}{10}{change.34}]
Undefined control sequence. [...s.}}{1}{20}}\nobreakspace {}}{10}{change.34}]
Undefined control sequence. [...s.}}{1}{20}}\nobreakspace
```

My question is: Is there a way to remove the commands from the input? Or maybe to de-command by removing the `\` or similar. I don't mind to have some extra garbage text around.

Thanks in advance!

### --- EDIT ---

I realised the problem is related to the command `\substring', which does not accept commands in the input string. Anyway, I'm not using it anymore.

Therefore, I'm closing this question.

Thank all for your help and sorry for the bothering.

**Solution** : Remove the command `\substring`

Comment: Try `\detokenize`.

Comment: Also, you should add a minimal working example. What are the packages you've loaded? Presumably `cleveref` and whatever packages provide `\substring` and `\removeabs`. The `textcolor` commands are probably unrelated to the problem -- have you tried removing them? What happens if you remove everything and just say `\addcontentsline{tod}{subsection}{#1}`? Does it still break?

Comment: Hi @HoodChatham thank for your comment. You made me consider the problem was with substring as indeed when I remove it, the command works perfectly.

Comment: What does happen when you put `\protect` in front of `\Cref` ?I.e., `\CoorAdd{ in figure \protect\Cref{fig.fig}}`